# var_dump return bool(false) and @mysql_ping() return true, why ?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, linux

Problem with mysql connection via php. I have simple database as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
         id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
         val INT
);
```

And when I do select in terminal connected with mysql:

```
 select * from test;
```

it  outputs normaly selected results.

The same selection I perform from php eg.:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hfh") or die("Unable to Connect");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test");
echo "results number: " . mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "<br/>";
echo mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "<br/>";
echo "results number: ";
echo "<br/>";
echo var_dump($result);
echo "<br/>";
echo @mysql_ping() ? 'true' : 'false';
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

and it gives me output:

```
results number:

results number:
bool(false)
true
```

When I make an insert like:

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO test (val) VALUES (55)");
```

It do not cause any problem.

What might be wrong above selection?

Comment: Do not mix `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*`

Comment: In fact, don't use `mysql_*()` at all - the functions are deprecated and will be removed.

Comment: That's it. Post it as an answer to mark as solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID LIMIT 3";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

/* numeric array */
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);

/* associative array */
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);

/* associative and numeric array */
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row["CountryCode"]);

/* free result set */
$result->free();

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

refer url: https://www.php.net/manual/zh/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php